# String.localeCompare returning incorrect value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm not sure if I'm simply formatting something incorrectly, misunderstanding the behavior of `localeCompare`, or if this function is actually broken but it seems like it handles numbers with different numbers of digits poorly.

`"0.75".localeCompare("0.5555", undefined, {numeric: true})`

Returns `-1`, but I would expect it to return `1`.

It seems like under the hood, this function is calling `parseInt` or something and doesn't handle decimal values reliably.

Comment: 75 is less than 5555. Why not just parse both as Numbers and compare?

Comment: But 0.75 is not less than 0.5555. I'm trying to use a single sort callback for all of my data if possible, which is not always numbers, and I can't just try to parse it as a number because it could be a string with numerals. Eg 'My trip to India in 2019'. I'd like to keep the sort agnostic of what 'category' I'm sorting if possible, but looking unlikely.

Comment: I see. Then you'd stop using `numeric` to sort decimals since that'll stop number collation. Then "0.75" will come after "0.5555" since "7" > "5"

Comment: While that works correctly for decimal values, it doesn't for values that have both decimal and characteristic values. Eg `"3".localeCompare("15")` gives 1.

Comment: Yes. So you'd have to check for decimal values

Comment: "implementations are not required to support this property" ... great, why do we even have a specification ... ? [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: You are comparing strings, so it makes sense if the greater string has a greater value

Comment: I'm explicitly telling the engine that I'm comparing numerical values, so it does not.